# create a table for search result

Tags: php, html, mysql

may I know how to create a HTML table for displaying my queries search results?

here is my code for search

```
<?php
//This connects the file to your database.
// Change the "database-username & database-password" to the one you've setup already.
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("smpi"); 

$search = $_POST['search']; 

$sql = mysql_query("select * from maklumat_pc where FName like '%$search%'"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  

     echo '<br/> Agensi: '.$row['Agensi'];
     echo '<br/> Jabatan: '.$row['Jabatan'];
     echo '<br/> Work Group: '.$row['Work_Group'];   
     echo '<br/> Computer Name: '.$row['Computer_Name'];
     echo '<br/> Kategori Infra: '.$row['Kategori_Infra'];
     echo '<br/> Nama Pengguna: '.$row['Nama_Pengguna'];
     echo '<br/> Jawatan: '.$row['Jawatan'];
     echo '<br/> Gred Jawatan: '.$row['Gred_Jawatan'];


    }

?>
```

Comment: What is Error or What you get ass output and what you need as output??

Comment: by "how to create a table" did you mean the html structure?? Could you be a bit more specific.

Comment: could you provide your sql table

Comment: The errors should be: `Warning: Don't use this -> mysql_*` and `Warning: Don't do this -> $search = $_POST['search']; ".....like '%$search%'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for show data as Table Format

```
<?php
    mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());  //This connects the file to your database. Change the "database-username & database-password" to the one you've setup already.
    mysql_select_db ("smpi");

    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maklumat_pc WHERE FName LIKE '%$search%'");
?>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Agensi</th>
        <th>Jabatan</th>
        <th>Work Group</th>
        <th>Computer Name</th>
        <th>Kategori Infra</th>
        <th>Nama Pengguna</th>
        <th>Jawatan</th>
        <th>Gred Jawatan</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Agensi'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Jabatan'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Work_Group'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Computer_Name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Kategori_Infra'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Nama_Pengguna'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Jawatan'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Gred_Jawatan'];?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> **Warning**
>   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future

Answer (score 1):

Something like this,

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead><tr><th>Agensi</th><th>Jabatan</th></thead>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
     echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.$row['Agensi'].'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$row['Jabatan'].'</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
echo '<table border="1">';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
 echo '<tr>';  
 echo '<td> Agensi: '.$row['Agensi'].'</td>';
 echo '<td> Jabatan: '.$row['Jabatan'].'</td>';
 echo '<td> Work Group: '.$row['Work_Group'].'</td>';   
 echo '<td> Computer Name: '.$row['Computer_Name'].'</td>';
 echo '<td> Kategori Infra: '.$row['Kategori_Infra'].'</td>';
 echo '<td> Nama Pengguna: '.$row['Nama_Pengguna'].'</td>';
 echo '<td> Jawatan: '.$row['Jawatan'].'</td>';
 echo '<td> Gred Jawatan: '.$row['Gred_Jawatan'].'</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```